# Is the word "sail" used when I talk about non-sail ship?

Tags: word-usage

So my question is basically about whether I can say "sail" when talking about ships that don't have a sail?

E.g.:
The military vessel **sailed** 1 hour ago

Is it correct to apply this word in such context?

Comment: Yes, the verb _to sail_ can be used, by extension, to refer to the movement of engine-propelled ships.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you for the answer! By the way, why did you say "by extension"? What did you mean?

Comment: @KateBunting and you can write your comment as an answer so that I can choose it as the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *to sail,* by extension of its original meaning referring to the movement of or travelling in a sailing vessel, can be used of an engine-propelled ship.